# Char and if stament in C

Tags: c

I have a problem to compare the char and "some text" inside `if` clause.
There is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char *start[99];
    printf("Welcome to MyOS 1");
    printf("\n" "#: ");
    scanf("%[98]", &start);
    if (&start == "help")
    {
        printf("All commands:" "File" "Calculator");
    }
}
```

Comment: Enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them. What do you think `start` actually is? Note: it is definitively not a `char` (which still was wrong to compare to a pointer).

Comment: to compare strings you must use strcmp or compare char by char see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c

Comment: Did you really want an array of char *pointers* and not simply `char start[99]`?

Comment: Ok i will try it thanks

Comment: @terencehill: `start`, even less `&start` is not a `char []` or `char *`.

Comment: Define start variable to be char array, so you could strcmp to compare between 2 strings.

Comment: @Olaf yes, i see, I just tried to point the OP to some starting post.

Answer (score 2):

`start` is an array of pointers to char and you probably want an array of char. So change

```
char *start[99];
```

to

```
char start[99];
```

and change `scanf("%[98]", &start);` to `scanf("%[98]", start);`

And to compare c-strings, use `strcmp()`. So change

```
 if (&start == "help")
```

to

```
 if ( strcmp(start, "help") == 0 )
```

If you want to read a *line*, use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) instead of `scanf()`.

Enabling compiler warnings would help too. For your code, GCC issues:

> warning: format ‘%[98’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument
>   2 has type ‘char * (*)[99]’ [-Wformat=]
>
> warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast
>
> warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified
>   behavior [-Waddress]

Comment: Thanks man this works. How i see i must continue to learn C better.

Comment: And i have i more question how the fgets() works and what parameters i must use for it or is it the same as scanf() ?

Comment: `fgets()` reads until it hits a `\n` or `EOF`. E.g. usage: `char buf[256]; fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);`. Note that `fgets()` would also read the `\n` if there's space in the buffer. So if you want to trim the newline, do: `char *p = strchr(p, '\n'); if(p) *p = 0;` after the call to `fgets()`.

Comment: Ok and do you have any good tutorial for C because i now only basics .

Comment: You can read [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for the recommendations. And you'll also find the [C-FAQs](http://c-faq.com/) pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code. You probably want an array of char, char start[99]. You should use strcmp or strncmp to compare strings. Just making your code work could be done like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char start[99];
    printf("Welcome to MyOS 1");
    printf("\n" "#: ");
    fgets(start, sizeof(start), stdin);
    if (isalpha((unsigned char) *start) != 0)
    {
        if (strncmp(start, "help", 4) == 0)
            printf("All commands: File Calculator\n");
        else
            printf("No such command.\n");
    }
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i dont understand fews thing in this code can you explain how its works ?

Comment: What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: The if (isalpha((unsigned char) *start) != 0) thats part

Comment: It checks  for  an alphanumeric character. It is just an extra check that you haven gotten something else as input. Try 'man 3 isalpha' for information on isalpha.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say it checks for an alphabetic character, not alphanumeric, that would be isalnum().